# How to display angular scope values inside a placeholder without using angular expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was using `angular expressions {{value}}` to display values inside elements.
But after I noticed that when there is a delay of loading , the unrendered expressions are still showed in the front end , I used `ng-bind` instead.

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span></h1>
</div>
```

So Using `ng-bind instead of {{ }}` will **prevent** the **unrendered {{ }} from showing up instead of empty elements being rendered**.

But now I have the same problem with a `input place holder`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name1"  placeholder=" Welcome {{name}} . Enter your question" ></input>
```

Same problem when loading delay. I don't need that curly braces to show up when there is a delay in loading. So how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the ' I don't need that curly braces to show up when there is a delay in loading' issue, I think you need to **load your javascript after all your styles and HTML have been loaded**.

To do this, just load your js files at the end of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using custom directive.

```
  var module = angular.module('practice', []);

module.controller('practiceCtrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.test = 'your placeholder text';



})
.directive('ngPlaceholder', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      placeholder: '=ngPlaceholder'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.$watch('placeholder',function() {
        elem[0].placeholder = scope.placeholder;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Providing the jsfiddle 
link below:

working  **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxf0k74c/2/)**